# Capturing Node routes that start with hash #

Tags: html, express, hash, routes

I'd like my Node/Express routing to be able to capture a route like

```
/#/about
```

and redirect it to

```
/about
```

Is this possible for node to capture any route that starts with "/#"? It seems to just truncate at the hash

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Routing - Express](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) there are some examples that show how you can use certain methods to achieve this. I'm not 100% sure but I think you could use the route:

```
(/#)?/about
```

Comment: It seems that the given expression captures "/about" but for "/#/about" it uses the "/" route